# Jquery DataTables plugin - hide columns name row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I'm developing a web app, which present few (~5) different data tables in different views.
I tried hiding the top row with the columns name, for just one of the data tables (but keep the other with this row), but with no success.
Most of the solutions I found are using CSS, which caused this row to disappear from all data tables in my app.
Does anybody know a good solution for that?

Here is an example of how I'm creating a data table in my app:

```
this._currentDiv = $('<div></div>');
this._stopsTable = $('<table></table>');
$(this._currentDiv).append(this._stopsTable);
$(this._currentDiv).append(self._stopsTable);
        $(this._currentDiv).append(data);
        $(this._stopsTable).dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bPaginate":false,
            "bLengthChange":false,
            "bFilter":false,
            "bSort":false,
            "bInfo":false,
            "bAutoWidth":false,
            "sScrollY": "100px",
            "aoColumns":[
                { "sTitle":"a" },
                { "sTitle":"b" },
                { "sTitle":"c" }
            ]
        });
```

and here is the css code I tried:

```
.dataTables_wrapper table thead {
    display:none;
}
```

I prefer a JavaScript solution if available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a javascript solution, you can use the `fnInitComplete` parameter of datatable.

```
$(this._stopsTable).dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate":false,
    "bLengthChange":false,
    "bFilter":false,
    "bSort":false,
    "bInfo":false,
    "bAutoWidth":false,
    "sScrollY": "100px",
    "aoColumns":[
        { "sTitle":"a" 
           "sTitle":"b" 
           "sTitle":"c" }
    ],
    "fnInitComplete" : function(oSettings, json) {
        // Find the wrapper and hide all thead
        $(this._stopsTable).parents('.dataTables_wrapper').first().find('thead').hide();
    }
});
```

When jQuery datatable use a scroll, the html structure is very different. jQuery datatables use a "second table" to handle the thead. So you can scroll and look at the thread anytime.
So if you want to remove the good thead, you need to retrieve the dataTable wrapper.

Of course, if you do that way for all tables, it will hide all thead of all your tables. So you must use something to know if you must hide the first row for the current table (a css class or an attribute on the table).

Here a jsfiddle as example : http://jsfiddle.net/LqSwt/5/

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. I put the code as you suggested, but the top raw did not disappear. Also, now I get the warning: "DataTables warning (table id = 'locationsTable'): The table cannot fit into the current element which will cause column misalignment. The table has been drawn at its minimum possible width. ". Maybe something is wrong with the way I initiate the table?

Comment: The code should do the same thing as your CSS. It's a weird warning. Can you make a jsfiddle with your code ?

Comment: Well it's quite complicated because it uses external libraries. Anyone?

Comment: @user1661304 you can add external libraries to the jsfiddle

Comment: @user1661304 I have done an edit on my response. And added a jsfiddle. Can you try this ? It should work now.

Comment: I had some unrelated problem regarding the data table init, and that's why it seems like it doesn't work. Now it is acting as it should. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

You should use css.  The table that you want to hide the column titles you need to give a separate class.  FYI - html elements can be assigned multiple classes, mostly for reasons like this.

so in your html when you declare the table, do it like this:

```
<table id="myTable" class="noHeader">
```

then in css you can use:

```
.noHeader thead { display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If scrolling is enabled (`sScrollX` / `sScrollY` is set in dataTables init options), dataTables will change the table structure like below:

```
div.dataTables_scroll
   div.dataTables_scrollHead
   div.dataTables_scrollBody
   [div.dataTables_scrollFoot]
```

And the thead is cloned to `div.dataTables_scrollHead > table`, the original thead in scrollBody is hidden, in order to get a fixed thead when scrolling vertically.

Thus, in your case, **you have to hide the cloned thead in `div.dataTables_scrollHead`**, you may do this in `fnInitComplete` callback as below:

```
"fnInitComplete": function(oSettings) {
    $('.dataTables_scrollHead thead').hide();
}
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/royling/eYCda/2/), hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: If no scrolling (neither `sScrollX` nor `sScrollY` is set), Magus's solution should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

What I think DataTables does is create two divs with separate tables in them.  It creates a "header" div with a nested table then the same for the body.

Try running this code after the table is complete, maybe even after the fnInitComplete handler suggested above.

```
$(.dataTables_scrollHeadInner).find("tr").hide(); //The class name may differ for you.  Use firebug to find class name of that div that contains your header.
```